# Is ChemiDay a reliable enough source (for inorganic reactions) to be cited on our site?

Tags: discussion, resources

We have quite [a lot of upvoted posts](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=Votes&q=url%3Achemiday.com) — 77 to be exact — using a website called ChemiDay as their reference material. However, from the looks of it, the website doesn't appear to be a reliable reference.

Suppose I have a question: "[What are the products of the reaction between fluorine and ammonia?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/25111/5026)" Now, this is the related [ChemiDay reaction](https://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-1065). The entire webpage only: states the reaction and gives a very short description:

> #### Ammonia react with fluorine
>
> $$\ce{2NH3 + 6F2 → 6HF + 2NF3}$$
>
> Ammonia react with fluorine to produce hydrogen fluoride and nitrogen(III) fluoride. The reaction takes place at the low temperature.

Most of the reactions in their database of ~17000 reactions (claimed) are like the one I linked to above. The question is: would we want the answer to this question be backed up by such a ChemiDay reference?

I instead would expect the answer to be backed by some reputed inorganic chemistry book (similar to March for organic), or at least a research paper - explaining the detailed experimental steps. For the above question, this [research paper](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01532a066) is apt. It clearly highlights major and minor products, and the different reactions at different yields of reactants.

I know we can't expect every answerer to be able to cite research papers or access good books, but does that mean we should sacrifice factual details and correctness with easy-to-lookup and (probably) wrong references?

So, should we officially disallow ChemiDay as a reference source (and leave a comment on such posts)? Or is there some other action we would want to take on such citations (for the past posts and for the future posts)?

Comment: Wikipedia has a “better citation needed” for this kind of thing, IIRC.

Comment: @orthocresol Definitely $^\text{[citation needed]}$; not sure about $^\text{[better citation needed]}$.

Comment: @hBy2Py apparently, it’s “better source needed”, which makes a bit more sense: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Better_source

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**No, it should not be considered a reliable source.**

From a quick once-over, it appears to be trying to be, among other things, something of an "encyclopedia of reactions."

A true encyclopedia always cites its sources. As you note, citations therein are ... scarce.

So no, as it is, it's no good.

Answer (score 3):

As you have noticed for some weeks that I am editing my old answers which has Chemiday as source (yes, my past-self is guilty of using Chemiday, please don't banish me :( ). I had around 15 such answers (I deleted 2-3 answers which was entirely Chemiday-crap and for the other answers, I edited and replaced the sources). By doing that, the answers became short and concise which looks good (before that it was more-or-less info-dumping).

Right now, [there are two posts containing the word "Chemiday" both of which are questions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VGtN.jpg)

Comment: Thanks Nilay! Now, 5 years later, I wouldn't probably bother with Chemiday references as long as the answer itself is correct. But I'm glad you took the time out to handle this 